# What is the correct/fastest way to negate @> in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

- I have a `text[]` column in Postgres 9.5
- I am planning on running a lot of queries with `@>` against it
- I have a GIN index on this column

Normally you need to use the correct Postgres operator so that an index is consulted for your query. There is no operator that is the "opposite" of  `@>` as far as I know.

I ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a query for this table and it takes **8 times** as long to run `WHERE NOT column @> array['thing']` as it does to run  `WHERE column @> array['thing']`. The planner reports that it does a `filter` for `WHERE NOT` instead of a bitmap index scan on my index.

What is the correct way to negate `@>` so that my index is consulted?

I'm willing to create new indexes for this column, including functional indexes if that's the answer.

Here are depesz links:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/uXOT
https://explain.depesz.com/s/nc7Q
https://explain.depesz.com/s/wC9m
https://explain.depesz.com/s/Eat

Comment: The problem here is likely that running `WHERE NOT column @> array['thing']` matches so many rows that the planner decides a different plan is better. It probably isn't selective enough. Or the selectivity estimates aren't good. If you, for testing purposes only, `SET enable_bitmapscan = off` and try again, is it slower or faster? What does explain show then? Show full `explain (buffers, analyze)` for all three queries as links to http://explain.depesz.com/ please.

Comment: @CraigRinger Ok, links added

Comment: The negated query returns 13285 rows and only 3171 rows do not match the criteria (80% of the rows of the table are returned). So Craig's assumption is right: the query simply returns too many rows in order to make an index scan efficient

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there another type of index I can build that optimizes for this situation? Or a different WHERE clause that is more efficient for this same result? (An item is not in an array column)

Comment: No index will help if you are retrieving a substantial part of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any highly effective way to index generic versions of that expression.  If you find a way to do so, I think you will be famous (well, famous within database circles, anyway).

If it is always exactly `NOT column @> array['thing']` where 'thing' does not change, you could build special-purpose indexes, like

```
create index on foo (("column" @> array['thing']));
```

(or a partial index version of that)

Once 9.6 is released, you will be able to do the seq scan in parallel, and so get a boost that way.